# Does AtomicExchange support 64-bit arguments?

Tags: delphi

The [documentation for AtomicExchange](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.AtomicExchange) gives the method signature as:

```
function AtomicExchange(var Target; Value: <Integer or NativeInt or Pointer>): Integer; overload;
function AtomicExchange(var Target; Value: <Integer or NativeInt or Pointer>): Int64; overload;
function AtomicExchange(var Target; Value: <Integer or NativeInt or Pointer>): Pointer; overload;
function AtomicExchange(var Target; Value: <Integer or NativeInt or Pointer>): NativeInt; overload;
```

But in practice it seems that `Int64` is also a valid argument, as:

```
function AtomicExchange(var Target; Value: <Integer or Int64 or NativeInt or Pointer>): Integer; overload;
function AtomicExchange(var Target; Value: <Integer or Int64 or NativeInt or Pointer>): Int64; overload;
function AtomicExchange(var Target; Value: <Integer or Int64 or NativeInt or Pointer>): Pointer; overload;
function AtomicExchange(var Target; Value: <Integer or Int64 or NativeInt or Pointer>): NativeInt; overload;
```

**NOTE:** Beyond the documentation, the IDE tooltips also suggest `Int64` is not a valid argument :

[image]

Can we, in fact, call `AtomicExchange` with an `Int64` argument, and is this expected to work correctly for 32-bit and 64-bit targets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation is incorrect, `AtomicExchange` is available for 64 bit operands. Many of the intrinsic functions are documented incorrectly, and this is yet another one.

Looking at the [`TInterlocked`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SyncObjs.TInterlocked) class methods which wrap the atomic intrinsic functions, it is a little more clear. There is this method:

```
class function TInterlocked.Exchange(var Target: Int64; Value: Int64): Int64;
begin
  Result := AtomicExchange(Target, Value);
end;
```

This makes it clear that `AtomicExchange` fully supports 64 bit values, even within a 32 bit process.